# Why does ls display a non-existing file?

Tags: directory, ls, wildcards

I want to list all the files whose name begins with uppercase:

```
[root@localhost /]# ls /usr/bin/[[:upper:]]*
/usr/bin/AtoB            /usr/bin/GenIssuerAltNameExt   /usr/bin/PKCS12Export
/usr/bin/AuditVerify     /usr/bin/GenSubjectAltNameExt  /usr/bin/POST
/usr/bin/BtoA            /usr/bin/GET                   /usr/bin/PrettyPrintCert
/usr/bin/CMCEnroll       /usr/bin/HEAD                  /usr/bin/PrettyPrintCrl
/usr/bin/CMCRequest      /usr/bin/HtFileType            /usr/bin/RSA_SecurID_getpasswd
/usr/bin/CMCResponse     /usr/bin/HttpClient            /usr/bin/RunSimTest
/usr/bin/CMCRevoke       /usr/bin/IBMgtSim              /usr/bin/TokenInfo
/usr/bin/CRMFPopClient   /usr/bin/Mail                  /usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/ExtJoiner       /usr/bin/OCSPClient            /usr/bin/Xorg
/usr/bin/GenExtKeyUsage  /usr/bin/PKCS10Client
```

It works OK, but when applied the current folder, it seem weird:

```
[root@localhost /]# ls ./[[:upper:]]*
snk321cq
[root@localhost /]# ls -lt snk321cq
ls: cannot access snk321cq: No such file or directory
[root@localhost /]# ls -lt ./snk321cq
ls: cannot access ./snk321cq: No such file or directory
```

Why display `snk321cq`? Actually there is no such a file.

Comment: Try `ls -b ./[[:upper:]]*`, or `ls ./[[:upper:]]* | cat -v`

Comment: @wurtel:It still diplays `snk321cq`.

Comment: OK, maybe you have a subdirectory whose name starts with a capital letter and that contains just one file `snk321cq`. Try `ls -d ./[[:upper:]]*` ... edit: Ah, I should have refreshed the page instead of clicking "show 1 more comment" :-) jlliagre came to the same conclusion before I did.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This file is under a directory matching the pattern, use:

```
ls -d ./[[:upper:]]*
```

By default, when passed a directory name as argument, `ls` displays its content, not its name. The `-d` option is disabling this feature.

When using the `[[:upper:]]*` pattern, the shell is expanding it to every filename starting with an uppercase letter so `ls` receives the expanded directory name.

Comment: Yeah, it is right. `ls -d ./[[:upper:]]*` displays a folder `Users`, and in this folder, there exists `snk321cq` folder. Why `ls ./[[:upper:]]*` will not display `Users`, instead displays its sub-folder name?

Comment: Answer updated with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to list the files/directories without their contents, better use

```
find  /usr/bin/ -maxdepth 1 -name "[[:upper:]]*"
```

Anyway better to use `find` than `ls` for finding files/dirs
`/usr/bin/Xvfb
/usr/bin/Mail
/usr/bin/GET
/usr/bin/POST
/usr/bin/HEAD
/usr/bin/Test`

and this way you can show the ls output of the find results:

`find  /usr/bin/ -maxdepth 1 -name [[:upper:]]* -ls
272304 1956 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root      1999608 Oct 18 07:48 /usr/bin/Xvfb
269561    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           15 Nov  4  2011 /usr/bin/Mail -> ../../bin/mailx
283683   16 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        14519 Aug 19  2010 /usr/bin/GET
283685   16 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        14519 Aug 19  2010 /usr/bin/POST
283684   16 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        14519 Aug 19  2010 /usr/bin/HEAD
 21421    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Jan 13 08:17 /usr/bin/Test`

Comment: You should quote `[[:upper:]]*` otherwise this command will fail if there are filenames starting with an uppercase character in the current directory. While there are cases where`find` is better than `ls`, your last command can be replaced by the much simpler `ls -dils /usr/bin/[[:upper:]]*`

Comment: Correct with the quotes :). But what do you mean by simple..? This is still a one line command with less flags than your suggestion... Plus, find is faster that ls.

Comment: You should edit your reply to fix the quote issues. By simpler, I mean easier to type, 32 keystrokes vs 52. Regarding performance, I doubt there would be any significant difference. The only case where `find` would be a better choice is for directories with a huge number of files matching the pattern.